# nd array manipulations are really slow

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to generate three sequences using np.(), but it takes a very long time. Following is my code:

```
mom_grid_number=1000
import codecs, json 
import time
import os,sys
import numpy as np
ts=time.time()
i_grid_seq = np.concatenate(\
                            [np.zeros(mom_grid_number**2,dtype=int)+i for i in range(mom_grid_number)])
j_grid_seq = np.transpose(\
                            np.concatenate(\
                                [np.zeros(\
                                    mom_grid_number**2,dtype=int)+i for i in range(mom_grid_number)]).reshape([-1,mom_grid_number])).reshape([1,-1])[0]
k_grid_seq = np.transpose(\
                            np.concatenate(\
                                [np.zeros(\
                                    mom_grid_number**2,dtype=int)+i for i in range(mom_grid_number)]).reshape([-1,mom_grid_number**2])).reshape([1,-1])[0]
te=time.time()
print(te - ts)
```

It takes around 166 seconds according to the printed time and I actually waited 5 minutes. Can anyone help me with this issue so it can run really fast?

Plus, I have gpu support in my pc if necessary for this issue.

Comment: You vould try `i_grid_seq, j_grid_seq, k_grid_seq = map(np.ravel, np.mgrid[:mom_grid_number, :mom_grid_number, :mom_grid_number])`

Comment: @ Paul Panzer. Yeah, it worked, but the speed is still not so fast. It is almost the same speed as the original one.

Comment: Well, you are asking for 3 x 10^9 numbers. What do you expect? Depending on what you want to do with the grid, you may be better off with an [open grid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html)

Comment: Well, if this the best we can get then it is fine. DO u think GPU computing would be helpful?

Comment: Not an expert, but AFAIK memory bandwidth is a major bottleneck with GPU computing, so I doubt this will help.Also, there is not much computing going on at this point, is there?

Comment: I am later going to use these parameters for several times, if I can condense the time consumption here, it would be faster.